# Use old email for login if new updated email is not verified

Tags: laravel, email, edit, verification

In edit profile, When the user edits existing email and updates new email, the new email should not be updated unless the user verify it. Meanwhile, The old one should be active. Please Help!

Comment: u need to maintain different  for updated email and once email is verified then update in `user` table problem solve

Comment: u need to modify your update email code u can easly do this if u know laravel

Answer (score 0):

what i did for this problem was i made a new table for edited information and it has all the fields of users table - like: UserEdit table
and store updated data in that table and when its verified i replaced this record in the User table
this will work for you. in this way you have your old data in case the updated informations hasnt accepted